How to propagate velocities correctly with tile based destructible physics objects
A somewhat complicated question but, I am working on a system where physics bodies can be made out of tiles. These tiles can be edited similar to a game like Terraria. When a body should logical be split I split it apart into two new bodies.
I am struggling with how to propagate velocities correctly. Obviously the linear velocity simply stays the same, but if an object is rotating and its end falls off how fast will that new piece be moving/rotating and in what direction? I have the distance from the center of the original object.
I am mostly just asking for a formula for something like this
